# objective-c, header file not found

Tags: objective-c, xcode4.2, inappsettings

I want to use [**InAppSettings**](https://github.com/InScopeApps/InAppSettings) in my iOS project. So I copied the InAppSettings folder into my project folder.

When I type

```
#import "InAppSettings.h"
```

xcode auto completes the import correctly. But after that it shows me that the file was not found. I copied the InAppSettings folder into the root folder of my project.

The file structure:

[image]

I want to import it in `FirstViewController.m`

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: What about `#import "InAppSettings/InAppSettings.h"`?

Comment: Does not work either...actually its in Project/Inappsettings/inappsettings/inappsettings.h

Comment: And where do you include it? Tell the path too

Comment: See my edit, I uploaded my file structure

Comment: Try to drag `InAppSettings` folder into project.

Comment: Where did you save InAppSettings folder on disk?

Comment: I selected "Copy files..." so the files are in my prject folder...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Last time the problem was that i imported the classes into eachother which makes XCode give that error. Could that be it?

Comment: Ok, I had this exact error which was removed by removing one of the imports. Guess yours has another reason.